# Using the URLconf defined in products.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-urls

```
*from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/',include('products.urls')),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
]*
```

The above code of pyshop/url.py
I could not login to admin page.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('products/new',views.new),
    path('products/',views.products),
    path('accounts/register',views.register),
]
```

The code is of product/urls.py.

Comment: Please check [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow. It is not clear fropm your question what you tried to do, what you expected and what happened.

Comment: make sure the admin url is present in url.py file of your project directory only ! Also have you created a superuser account ? Also mention what type of error you are getting so that i can help you better.

Comment: admin url is present in url.py. I have already created superuser account. however after adding static template pages and I can not accessed admin page. Here is my  code of view.py                                                                                                                      
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
        return render(request, 'index.html')

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I run into the same problem, so just in case I can help someone else.

I would put in the pyshop/url.py, this code (see the admin path is the only one with an actual url):

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('products.urls')),
    path('',include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

Then in your product/urls.py (See all of the routes end with a slash):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name="product"),
        path('products/new/',views.new, name="new_product"),
        path('products/',views.products, name="products"),
        path('accounts/register/',views.register, name="register"),
    ]
```